# why Show data in Angle brackets 'example',) in Django Form

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

HTML CODE

{% csrf_token %}

```
           <input type="text" name="sub1" value="{{sub1}}" placeholder="Sub 1">
           <input type="text" name="sub2" value="{{sub2}}" placeholder="Sub 2">
           <input type="text" name="sub3" value="{{sub3}}" placeholder="Sub 3">
           <input type="text" name="sub4" value="{{sub4}}" placeholder="Sub 4">
           <input type="text" name="sub5" value="{{sub5}}" placeholder="Sub 5">

           <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
       </form>
```

VIEWS FUNCTION

def Contact(request):
data= {}
try:
if request.method=="POST":

```
        sub1= request.POST.get('sub1'),
        sub2= int(request.POST.get('sub2')),
        sub3= int(request.POST.get('sub3')),
        sub4= int(request.POST.get('sub4')),
        sub5= int(request.POST.get('sub5')),  
        Total_num = sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5       
        print(sub1)          
        data = {
                'Total_num':Total_num,
                'sub1':sub1
                }
except:
    pass       
return render(request,"contact.html",data)
```

OUTPUT
{{sub1}}
Result
('ad',)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the trailing commas: by the comma at the end, you wrap the value in a singleton tuple. By removing the comma, you get the real value, so:

```
sub1 = request.POST.get('sub1')
sub2 = int(request.POST.get('sub2'))
sub3 = int(request.POST.get('sub3'))
sub4 = int(request.POST.get('sub4'))
sub5 = int(request.POST.get('sub5'))
Total_num = sub1+sub2+sub3+sub4+sub5
```